# How to update a javascript/json object based on a string defining path of field to be inserted to object

Tags: javascript

My object is already defined.
I want to insert variables at particular indexes in the object.

Given message object:

```
message=[{
  person:{
      actions:[{test:1},{test:2}]
  },
  person:{}
},
{
  person:{
      actions:[{test:3},{test:4}]
  },
  person:{}
}]
```

1) If my string = "message[0].person.actions[1].visible".
This means I need to insert `visible=null` at index=1 of actions.
**So message object becomes:**

```
message=[{
  person:{
      actions:[{test:1},{test:2,visible:null}]
  }
},
{
  person:{
      actions:[{test:3},{test:4}]
  }
}]
```

2) If string="message[1].person.accessible",
   **So message Object become**:

```
message=[{
  person:{
      actions:[{test:1},{test:2}]
  }
},
{
  person:{
      accessible:null,
      actions:[{test:3},{test:4}]
  }
}]
```

I thought of doing split('[') and get that index and insert in that object.
Let me know if there are any libraries out there simplifying this for more complex data structure.

**This question got closed along with a link to question** [[Accessing nested JavaScript objects with string key](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6491463/accessing-nested-javascript-objects-with-string-key])
My question is different than above mentioned link. I am asking about inserting a new field at particular location in object.

Comment: You would use the code in the associated question to traverse your object. Which is a huge piece of what you need to do to add a new property. Your next steps would be something along the lines of removing the new field from the string, then traversing your object, then assiging the property.

Answer (score 0):

Just mutate the object by assigning it a property.

`message[0].person.actions[1].visible = null;`

This should work.

Comment: `"message[0].person.actions[1].visible"` is a string in my case, not sure what you mean by mutate. This string tells that I need to insert visible at action's index=1